# Render HTML table on Windows Mobile 6.0

Tags: html, windows-mobile

I am trying to render a HTML table to display on Windows Mobile 6.0 device. I use Mobile Device Emulator to view the output. Here is my html, am I missing something? The table display each cell on it own row.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.0//EN"
           "http://www.wapforum.org/DTD/xhtml-mobile10.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head><title>

</title></head>

<body> 
   <form name="form1" method="post" action="Default.aspx" id="form1"> 
      <div>   
        <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" 
              value="/wEPDwULLTE2MTY2ODcyMjlkZAKh+guFjex39kxMbH4g4N/KD/cn" /> 
      </div>

      <div> <ul><li>Test</li><li>Blah12</li></ul>

      <table border="1">
        <tbody>
         <tr><td>Row 1, Col 1</td><td>Row 1, Col 2</td></tr>
         <tr><td>Row 2, Col 1</td><td>Row 2, Col 2</td></tr>
        </tbody> 
      </table> 

      </div> 
    </form> 
</body> 
</html>
```

@DanHerbert's answer is user can switch the browser on the phone to "Desktop" mode. The second part of this question is there a meta tag to instruct the mobile to use "Desktop" mode instead of "Column" mode?

Comment: Your doctype and html lines look weird. (&gt and &quot;) Is that how they look in your file?

Comment: @Nosredna, I fixed the HTML formatting. I'm assuming the asker is not familiar with markdown syntax, which looks like the cause of the formatting issues.

Comment: Dan thank you for fixing my HTML formating. Yes I try to embed the html block between `.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the View mode of the browser.

Windows mobile will try to "optimize" table layout if you use the default "*Single Column*" (or it might be called "One Column") view.

You should make sure the browser is set to use "*Desktop*" mode or else the columns will display incorrectly.

**UPDATE:**
To do this through a meta tag, add the following to your page:

```
<meta name="MobileOptimized" content="width">
```

Taken from Microsoft's documentation:

[`http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms890014.aspx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms890014.aspx)

Comment: @DanHerbert, thank you. The MSDN documentation also a great help, I was searching all over for this.